# Installing java on Ubuntu Amazon aws

Tags: server, java, amazon-ec2

I want to install java in an Ubuntu server in the Amazon aws. How Can I find the model number of that server so I can install the right version of java?

Answer (score 8):

Run `lsb_release -a` to find the version of Ubuntu you are running.

If you are running 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

If you are running 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```